# how to parse invalid json string (with hex values)

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem parsing a json string.

Here's the string (the problematic part of it):

```
{
    "type":"meaning",
    "terms":[
    {
       "type":"text",
       "text":"some value.",
       "language":"ru"
    },
    {
       "type":"url",
       "text":"\x3ca href\x3d\x22http://readmas.ru/arts/bodyart/znachenie-tatuirovok.-chast-i.html\x22\x3…ttp://readmas.ru/arts/bodyart/znachenie-tatuirovok.-chast-i.html\x3c/a\x3e",
       "language":"ru"
   }]
},
```

Note:
These function doesn't work for me:

1. string `replace`.
2. `JSON.parse`.
3. `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: this is looking ok  please tell us much more about problem

Comment: I'm actually developing a chrome extension and this string is returned to me by google dictionary. I can't change the way the request is beind made (because it is the only way to get an answer from google). Here's the request:

Comment: There are no workarounds, except maybe a search and replace on the string itself, as you have invalid JSON, and it can't be parsed.

Comment: var url = "https://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=_&q=" + word + "&sl=ru&tl=ru&restrict=pr%2Cde&client=te";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (responseText) {
            var code = responseText.trim().substr(2, responseText.lastIndexOf("}") - 1);
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });

Comment: string replace isn't working for me. is there any other way to replace the invalid characters before parsing an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript, the [JSON notation](http://www.json.org/) only supports the two-byte `\uNNNN` escape sequences, not the `\xNN` sequences. Try this:

```
var cleaned = input.replace(/\\x([0-9a-f]{2})/g, '\\u00$1');
var output = $.parseJSON(cleaned);
console.log(output);
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/LDcnE/)

Also, in order to make this demonstration work, I had make a couple other modifications to your string, which I think are just a result of how you formatted the question here:

- Completed the `\xNN` escape sequence that was broken when in the middle of the string (`\x3…ttp`).
- Removed the comma at the end of the object literal.

In any case, it would probably be better if you could make your service (or whatever is giving you this file) provide you valid JSON instead this.